# Best way to troubleshoot custom web part without original source code?

Tags: 2013, web-part

We have been asked to troubleshoot a custom web part in SharePoint 2013 on-premises.  The problem is that we are unable to determine exactly what it's trying to do, as we were not given the source code (and the client cannot find it).  What are my best options in this scenario?

I understand we might be able to extract the web-part WSP from the farm using PowerShell, but I don't think that will help us with any compiled DLLs that it might contain? Also, am I likely going to be able to update the WSP afterwards and redeploy (in the event a code change is needed)?

Thanks in advance for any tips or tricks.

Answer (score 0):

Download the WSP file from the production server CA using the PowerShell script, then you can rename **.wsp** file to **.cab** file. Extract it. Once extracted you will get all files and assembly. Either use REFLECTOR or ILSPY to get the code of assembly. So once you have code you can copy-paste in visual studio. This process is called reverse engineering.

Once you get the source code - first deploy this solution in the dev or test server and debug it - it will give you more clarity about the source code what exactly it is doing.

References:

[Convert .wsp file into SourceCode?](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/forums/convert-wsp-file-into-sourcecode)

[SharePoint 2010: Reverse Engineering SharePoint WSP Packages](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/17546.sharepoint-2010-reverse-engineering-sharepoint-wsp-packages.aspx)